# All badges site-wide have incorrect padding

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Today, there was a site-wide CSS change on "badge tags".

**The left padding on all badges increased, making all of our badges look off-center.**

Here's what they looked like before:

[image: Badge tags]

**How they look now:**

[image]

It looks awful to me, because I'm used to how they were before.

---

**Technical details:**

Relevant CSS styling before:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em .4em .6em;
}
```

And what they changed it to:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em;
}
```

You can experiment with this by right-clicking on any badge in Chrome or Firefox and going to Inspector, and finding the `padding` attribute in there.

---

**Is this something we'll have to fix on our own with user-styles? Or can this be fixed by the site owner?**

Comment: I like the new padding - anarchyyyyy!!!!

Comment: Woa... you're right. Old one was definitely better

Comment: Upvoted just to keep the only answer having a score of exactly negative of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've restored the previous style:

```
.badge-tag {
  padding: .4em .8em .4em .4em;
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! All of us perfectionists can now comfortably continue our SE routine. Again, thanks for the update!

Answer (score -21):

you can use this css:

```
.badge1, .badge2, .badge3{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This code ruins the spacing of badge counts in the "Joined Communities" section, and only works for sites that use "circles" for badge color icons.

Comment: Also, I didn't ask for code. I asked if the site owner was going to fix it or if we're gonna have to use user styles.

Comment: Also, @AaronGillion alraedy showed the correct code for a fix.